# query oracle datetime to retrieve only date

Tags: sql, oracle, reporting-services

I know this is simple but am having great difficulty, I need to take a query field that is datetime and convert it so that it is only date no time.

```
 SELECT COSTLABR.CHARGDTTM
 FROM imsv7.costlabr
```

Gets me the datetime field from chargdttm but I need it to only be date, or as an alternative the time to be exactly the same for every row returned.

This has got to be simple but it is eluding me. 
Thanks in advance!
Steven

Comment: This has been asked several times already. Be sure to check for answers before asking a question.

Comment: @Ageonix  Honestly I have been searching for hours, appartently did not hit the right key words or something, the one you linked to looks to be exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks!

Comment: @Ageonix - I did a search for dups and didn't find one that I thought fit the bill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`TRUNC` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions209.htm#i79761) to truncate dates:

```
SELECT TRUNC(COSTLABR.CHARGDTTM)
   FROM imsv7.costlabr
```

will set the HOURS, MINUTES, and SECONDS portions of the date column to zero, in effect changing the time to the preceding midnight.

Comment: that worked exactly like I was hoping for thank you!